# Used an Update Statement without Where clause in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, plsqldeveloper

I executed an update statement mistakenly without any where clause in pl/sql developer.I did click on the break button when I found what had happened after some time when the execution was taking time to complete, commit and rollback buttons were grayed out after breaking the execution hence could not roll back the transaction. I am worried if break button commits the transaction in pl/sql developer or it roll backs to the previous state.

Comment: Allround Automation's PL/SQL Developer and Oracle SQL Developer are two different tools from two different vendors. You have tagged your question with both, which is confusing. Please edit your question to make it clear which product you're using.

Comment: okay have updated the tag, I am working on pl/sql developer tool.

Comment: Those who live by the GUI, die by the GUI. So what if "Rollback" button is grayed out? There's the `rollback;` statement you can execute.

Comment: yeah, I know but the deed is already done @Littlefoot, any idea if the break button commits or does a rollback if it is hit in middle of the execution of update query?, appreciate your help thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't know, @newbee. Manual (https://origin2.componentsource.com/sites/default/files/resources/allround-automations/533856/manual.pdf) doesn't describe the behaviour either. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PL/SQL Developer's Break key does not commit, it just breaks the current operation and leaves things as they were at the start of it, including any open transactions. For example, if you did three updates without committing, and then started a fourth but used the Break key to interrupt it, you would still have the first three uncommitted updates, and the Commit and Rollback icons would be active.

The icons were greyed out because there was no transaction to commit. PL/SQL Developer sets their status by calling `dbms_transaction.local_transaction_id` after every statement to check for an open transaction.

If you didn't see the *"Are you sure?"* warning popup, you might check *Configure > User Interface > Options > DSA Dialogs* in case you previously clicked "OK" on a "Don't show this message again" popup.

Comment: Thanks! that clears my doubt, I was not having any active transactions before this update statement hence it must have gone to the previous state not updating anything and leaving the icons greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

First step is to be cool.. otherwise you won't able to think properly.

Immediately execute Rollback command.

Then run a query to select the updated field and check whether the result contains any values other than updated value.

for example if you executed below query,

update Employees set Status = 'Inactive' you should check whether the status column contains any value other than 'Inactive'

If the column contains any value other than updated value, you are good and fine.

the system rolled back that update statement.

If the column doesn't contains value other than the updated values, please connect with the database administrator to rollback this transaction.

They will able to do this without much hassle.

Comment: Hi Shrias, I used break button to stop update from execution, commit and rollback buttons were grayed out could you please tell me if break rollbacks the transaction or commits it..thanks

Comment: I believe 99% that transaction got cancelled. But to confirm that please write a query to select updated column and see any values other than updated value.. since transaction is atomic in nature.. means either it has applied the change to all data or nothing.

Comment: okay, the data size is a bit big to check upon, hopefully it got cancelled as you stated, thank you,